# WatchOS notifications - Custom dynamic interface only occurs when received

Tags: apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, watch-notification

My iOS app has given my a default dynamic notification interface for free including its action.

I want to customize my own dynamic notification interface using `class NotificationController: WKUserNotificationInterfaceController`

I took a few tests and the whenever I manually open a new notification from the dock the default notification interface occurs and not my customized notification interface. But when I receive my notification, my customized notification interface appears

I how to avoid using the default, since there are actions on the default interface I don't want to use for my app.